# JavaScript binding of global result is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I looked below code in blog cause i wanna know about this.

[image]

When i copy & paste this code and then execute that.

The result is different.

[image]

The result of bike is undefined. But i dont know why result is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is so because , global scope in browser and nodejs are different. When you declare a **var** in browser , variable is attached to global scope and can be accessed by **this** operator. Where as it is not the case with nodejs.

So if you copy paste and run this code in browser it would work as expected.

[More clarification](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)